"Too many SOQL queries" error and other strange things in Recommendation Strategy Flow
I have a Recommendation Strategy Flow, used in Einstein Next Best Actions for a Case. The start of it looks like this:

Sometimes I get a batch of "Too many SOQL queries" errors from this flow. The strange thing is: it stops in this first element "Get Current Case", which should only be one SOQL query. And the error e-mail claims that no records could be found, even though the Case, to which it refers, exists. And has existed for some time.
For days this flow runs without errors and then suddenly, I get about 10 at the same time, for 10 different Cases. They are always caused by the same user, even though another user does the same kind of work on Cases.
I have looked at the permissions and properties of both users and I have not been able to find any differences.
The user, for which I get these error e-mails, does not notice anything. Next Best Actions are presented without apparent problems.
So, from an operational point of view, not really a problem, as the users are able to do their jobs. But something is not right, and I don't know what I can do about it.
The usual suspect for such errors would be a trigger or another flow, but this flow simply looks up a Case, given an Id. It should not trigger anything, should it?
Update half a year later: for months, this flow has run without problems. And all of a sudden: dozens of these errors again. I have no clue what is going on.

I'd suspect there's some flow bulkification going on here and something is getting confused. Having not used next best actions myself, I can add nothing more.
